# How to pass a definiton of 3D object to an app durign the runtime?

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d

In my application I'm drawing a simple 3D object (at the end of the question you will find the code of it). I'm drawing it using `GL10` object.

Now I want to go one step further and pass the definition of such object during the runtime. I want to build and inject and object in method that will get the definition from my webservice.

Any tip how to start ?

```
public class SimpleBox {
private FloatBuffer box;
private FloatBuffer normals;
public SimpleBox() {
    float boxf[] =  {
            // FRONT
            -25.0f, -25.0f,  25.0f,
             25.0f, -25.0f,  25.0f,
            -25.0f,  25.0f,  25.0f,
             25.0f,  25.0f,  25.0f,
            // BACK
            -25.0f, -25.0f, -25.0f,
            -25.0f,  25.0f, -25.0f,
             25.0f, -25.0f, -25.0f,
             25.0f,  25.0f, -25.0f,
            // LEFT
            -25.0f, -25.0f,  25.0f,
            -25.0f,  25.0f,  25.0f,
            -25.0f, -25.0f, -25.0f,
            -25.0f,  25.0f, -25.0f,
            // RIGHT
             25.0f, -25.0f, -25.0f,
             25.0f,  25.0f, -25.0f,
             25.0f, -25.0f,  25.0f,
             25.0f,  25.0f,  25.0f,
            // TOP
            -25.0f,  25.0f,  25.0f,
             25.0f,  25.0f,  25.0f,
             -25.0f,  25.0f, -25.0f,
             25.0f,  25.0f, -25.0f,
            // BOTTOM
            -25.0f, -25.0f,  25.0f,
            -25.0f, -25.0f, -25.0f,
             25.0f, -25.0f,  25.0f,
             25.0f, -25.0f, -25.0f,
        };
    float normalsf[] =  {
            // FRONT
            0.0f, 0.0f,  1.0f,
            0.0f, 0.0f,  1.0f,
            0.0f, 0.0f,  1.0f,
            0.0f, 0.0f,  1.0f,
            // BACK
            0.0f, 0.0f,  -1.0f,
            0.0f, 0.0f,  -1.0f,
            0.0f, 0.0f,  -1.0f,
            0.0f, 0.0f,  -1.0f,
            // LEFT
            -1.0f, 0.0f,  0.0f,
            -1.0f, 0.0f,  0.0f,
            -1.0f, 0.0f,  0.0f,
            -1.0f, 0.0f,  0.0f,
            // RIGHT
            1.0f, 0.0f,  0.0f,
            1.0f, 0.0f,  0.0f,
            1.0f, 0.0f,  0.0f,
            1.0f, 0.0f,  0.0f,
            // TOP
            0.0f, 1.0f,  0.0f,
            0.0f, 1.0f,  0.0f,
            0.0f, 1.0f,  0.0f,
            0.0f, 1.0f,  0.0f,
            // BOTTOM
            0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,
            0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,
            0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,
            0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,
        };

    box = GraphicsUtil.makeFloatBuffer(boxf);
    normals = GraphicsUtil.makeFloatBuffer(normalsf);
}


public final void draw(GL10 gl) {   
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);

    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, box);
    gl.glNormalPointer(GL10.GL_FLOAT,0, normals);
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 4, 4);
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 8, 4);
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 12, 4);
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 16, 4);
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 20, 4);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can for instance pass a JSON from server which would give you the data something like:

```
    {
        vertex_count: 30,
        vertices: [
            {x: 0, y: 0, z: 0, nx: 0, ny: 1, nz: 0},
            {x: 1, y: 1, z: 1, nx: 0, ny: 1, nz: 0},
            {x: 0, y: 1, z: 0, nx: 0, ny: 1, nz: 0},
            {x: 1, y: 0, z: 0, nx: 0, ny: 1, nz: 0},
            {x: 1, y: 1, z: 0, nx: 0, ny: 1, nz: 0},
            ...
        ]
        ...
    }
```

This way you can create 2 buffers to be the same as in your code. Then iterate through the `vertices` in the JSON and append the values to the 2 float buffers. Once everything is done you can simply assign the buffers to your `box` and `normals` and the new object will overwrite the old one so the new one should be shown.

Comment: This the route that I've choose. The only problem is to getting proper format to the DB that is serving it to the app. Even if I conver 3D obejct to the Waveform format (.obj) I still need to know how to connect the points but this is good solution I think

Comment: Well you could simply serve the obj files and download them in the runtime. It would then mean you need to parse them on the client which is still a pain... So as long as you need to parse them somewhere it might be better doing it on the server side but in any case you would then still need to serve the mtl material files and the texture files. It really depends on what exactly are you targeting but if you want the speed it would be best to parse the obj into binary on the server and then send the binary to the client.

Comment: ...the binary wold then mean something like: first 32 bits is an integer representing a number of vertices. Then you could define that a vertex is represented by 32bit floats where a single vertex has 8 floats (3 for position, 3 for normal, 2 for texture coordinates). So for instance a model having 100 vertices would send a 3208 bytes of binary data from this map. (This is all just one of many ways you can define your model). But it can get complicated as the data can then be followed by index buffer using the same procedure so another 32 bits for length followed by index buffer...

Comment: Thank you Matic. This is very interesting. I need to perform some tests but you really shown me a very interesting path !!